# MYSQL, PHP, image upload/update fail

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

i am trying to allow users to update their profile picture using this code.

```
   require("../connection.php");

   $imgName = $_FILES['pic']['name']; 
   $imgTmp = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']; 
   $imgtype = $_FILES['pic']['type'];
   $imgSize = $_FILES['pic']['size'];

   $maxFileSize = 200000;
   $pic = "../uploads/" . $user_id . "_" . time() . $imgName;

   if ($imgSize > $maxFileSize) {
       $error = "size";
   }
   if ($imgType == "image/jpeg" || $imgType == "image/gif") {
       $error .= "";
   } else {
       $error = "type";
   }
   if (file_exists($pic)) {
       $error = "exists";
   }
   if ($error == "" && $imgName != "") {


   move_uploaded_file($imgTmp, $pic);

   mysql_query("UPDATE users SET pic = '$pic', WHERE username = '$username'");


if (!mysql_query($query, $connect)) {
die(mysql_error());
   } else {
mysql_close($connect);
header('location:http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/users/upload-pic-thanks.php');
}
   } else {
header("Location:edit-pic-error.php?e=".$error);
}
```

and it gives me this in the address bar: edit-pic-error.php?e=type, however the file i am trying to upload is .jpg, and its smaller than the 20000kb allowance.

The table in my mysql database is called 'users', and the table row is called 'pic', its Varchar, 60, allow null ticked.

The table is not being updated with the new time stamped profile picture.

Please help.

Thanks very much

Comment: What errors are reported or appear in the error log?

Comment: I dont get any errors, it simply sends me to the error page header, and places edit-pic-error.php?e=type in the address bar, which would suggest the type is wrong. but its .jpeg so should be fine...

Comment: what is the value of `$imgType` if it's not "image/jpeg" ?

Comment: I'm not sure. But $imgType is there to state what is accepted.

Comment: Check php log and apache error log. Despite the fact your browser shows no errors, the might be in log.

Comment: you don't have to guess what `$imgType` is. PHP can tell you: `echo $imgType`

Comment: have tried print_r($imgType); die(); throughout the code and it shows nothing different..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$imgtype = $_FILES['pic']['type'];`

`if ($imgType == "image/jpeg" || $imgType == "image/gif") {`

$imgType vs. $imgtype, notice the case.